# Scanning across a universe of stocks for triggers in R

Tags: r

First of all, I apologize if this is a basic question, however I searched here and was unable to find an answer to what I'm trying. I'm not new to programming, but I am new to R (and my programming is a bit rusty, as I've changed career focus a bit).

What I'm trying to do is a fairly simple (famous last words):

- Every morning
- scan across the entire universe of stocks (or just the S&P 500)
- show me any stock that is within x% of a given indicator (eg, approaching lower bollinger band)

This is how I'm trying to do a proof of concept, and the use that as a launching pad for developing my own indicators. I appreciate any and all helpful comments, links, etc. Thanks in advance all!

Comment: I posted an answer, but this not a good question for S.O.  We expect you to try something first, and when you have trouble, come ask for specific help.  Here, you're just asking us to do a task for you however we see fit, which is a bit broad.

Comment: Feedback much appreciated. Unfortunately, with quantmod and quantstrat, the documentation is so disjointed (or absent) that finding a sane starting point (especially for an R beginner) was proving very difficult. I appreciate your answer -- it has served as a launching pad for my project (I already modified it to look for upper bands as well, and look for a few other indicators). Thanks again.

Comment: If you have a moment, could you please explain this statement: names(near.low.band)[near.low.band]. I've been digesting it (and I understand the result it gives), but I'm not sure I understand quite WHY it gives those results. Thanks.

Comment: See [Section 2.7 of An Introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Index-vectors). I'm using a [logical vector](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Logical-vectors) to subset itself.  Play around with this and let me know if it is still unclear: `x <- setNames(c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE), c("A", "B", "C"));x;x[x];names(x[x]);names(x)[x];`

Comment: Thank you! I saw what was happening by executing line by line, but wasn't sure I was understanding why. This was extremely helpful, thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(quantmod)

# a vector of stock tickers to look at
s <- c("AA", "AXP", "BA", "BAC", "CAT", "CSCO", "CVX", "DD", "DIS", 
"GE", "HD", "HPQ", "IBM", "INTC", "JNJ", "JPM", "KO", "MCD", 
"MMM", "MRK", "MSFT", "PFE", "PG", "T", "TRV", "UNH", "UTX", 
"VZ", "WMT", "XOM")

e <- new.env()  # an environment to hold our data
getSymbols(s, from=Sys.Date()-50, src="yahoo", env=e) # download stock prices

# create a parameter
pct <- 0.01 # look for close prices that are lower than 1% above lower bband.

# eapply loops over every object in the environment and applies a function to it.
# our function calculates the value of the lower BBand increased by "pct"
# Then it returns TRUE or FALSE depending on whether the stock price is below that.
# eapply returns a list, which we can `unlist` into a named vector
near.low.band <- unlist(eapply(e, function(x) {
  bband.dn <- as.numeric(last(BBands(HLC(x))$dn))
  as.numeric(last(Cl(x))) <  bband.dn * (1 + pct)
}))

# get the names where the value is TRUE
names(near.low.band)[near.low.band]
# [1] "XOM"  "JNJ"  "JPM"  "VZ"   "UTX"  "INTC" "MMM"  "MCD"  "CSCO" "PFE" 
#[11] "GE"   "T"    "BAC"  "CVX"  "MRK"  "TRV"  "KO"   "PG"   "WMT"  "DIS" 
#[21] "UNH"  "HD"   "BA"   "IBM" 

# And the ones that are not below our threshold?
names(near.low.band)[!near.low.band]
#[1] "DD"   "HPQ"  "AXP"  "AA"   "CAT"  "MSFT"
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast, and incredibly concise, response!